# Finding $\lim (3^x-e^x)/(7x^{15}+5x^{25})$ as $x\to+\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to find the limit of $(3^x-e^x)/(7x^{15}+5x^{25})$ as $x\to+\infty$ using only notable limits (I can't use Taylor series or de l'Hopital's method). I'm stuck in finding this limit, I tried to substitute x with ln(y) so that I can use logarithm's properties but I can't finish it. Looking to the limit's form I can't use notable limits because x approaches to +infinity so the parts of notable limits that are involved here can't be use in my favour..
Please help me with a clear solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac {3^x-e^x}{7x^{15}+5x^{25}}=\frac {3^x(1- (\frac {e}{3})^x)}{x^{25}(7x^{-10}+5)}$$.

$$(\frac {e}{3})^x\to 0$$,$$7x^{-10}\to 0$$ and $$\frac {3^x}{x^{25}} \to \infty $$ using Hospital  the last one.

So the limit is ?

Comment: the limit of (e/3)^x is 0 because 3^x goes faster to infinity than e^x right?

Comment: yes,because $e<3$

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{3^x-e^x}{7x^{15}+5x^{25}}=\infty$

Comment: This is a (correct) answer, not a solution.